# How to Keep a Row Highlighted after a Page Refreshes in Oracle Apex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I have two reports. Clicking on a column link in the primary report reveals details about it in the secondary report, and clicking the link refreshes the page (Maybe if only the second report was refreshed using AJAX I wouldn't have the following problem, but I figure this will be harder to implement and maintain).

I have a javascript function like this to highlight the row:

```
function highlight(pThis) {
    $x_RowHighlight($x_UpTill(pThis,'TR'), 'pink');
}
```

But the row of course does not remain highlighted when the page refreshes. I would love to maintain the session state of pThis, if that is possible.

I also have a requirement to place a next button in the secondary report, that would show the details of the next row in the primary report, and highlight that row as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your primary report contain some sort of unique key by any chance (such as an ID), in the HTML? And not in a column that can be hidden by the user? There are several issues that make this technique hard to achieve with an IR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together an example page with all code on it: http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54687:39

I've made it a bit more involved because i wanted to account for a column link. When the link is clicked, the row has to become highlighted aswell. Note that it will only work as long as you remain on the same page (or rather, as long as you are on the same IR page) like this. I now even notice that it'll keep the row colored when you navigate to the page and reset pagination - oh well, this is a good jumping point.

I used the rowindex for a good reason: a good solution for an IR doesn't really exist, and will always be very much custom coded. You'd actually need a value(or values) by which you could uniquely identify rows. That gives some problems since for example hidden columns are not rendered in the HTML. If it is in column, it could very well be that users can hide or in some way remove the column from the html (don't display it, apply grouping,...).

---

I've edited my example application page to include a way to deal with classic reports too, after viewing Matthew's own answer. I'll try to pick it apart a bit.
1) i wouldn't 'hide' my column by reducing the width. Just hide your column using the column attributes and change the type to hidden.
2) you don't really need a column item, unless you really mean to remember that. But i don't really see the point of it unless you allow clicking an entire row (as i did in my IR example, but i dismissed that idea for the classic report)
3) (a+b+c) I did this completely different. I think it is a much better way to assign a class to the row element, as this allows much better manipulation and traverse. The `$x_RowHighlight` function adds a `style` attribute to the `td` elements, and i don't like that. Controlling the style through a class and CSS is much more versatile.
I'd also argue that AJAX is not required here! When you click the link, you can directly set the item value and not go through an ajax call. I'd also argue that this does not need to be a synchronous call (which htmldb_Get is by default), but can be asynchronous as to not make the browser wait for a return (there is none).
Nevertheless, you could require ajax if you want to set it up as in my IR example so that clicking anywhere on a row would select the row.
As for selecting the next row: in my example you'd need to replace the changing of the input item to a click on the link column - shouldn't be to hard!

---

Performing an async call with htmldb_Get:

```
var ajaxRequest = new htmldb_Get(null, $v("pFlowId"), "APPLICATION_PROCESS=some_process", $v("pFlowStepId"));
ajaxRequest.addParam("x01","some value"); -- adds a parameter to the request, good for the x## variables
ajaxRequest.add("P1_EMPNO", "some value"); -- adds the key-value to p_args_names en values: page items!
ajaxRequest.getAsync(function(pResponse){
   if(pResponse.readyState==4&&pResponse.status==200){
      //call finished successfully
      console.log(pResponse.responseText);
   };
});
```

Comment: Hey Tom, I took a trip this week starting on the 13th and won't be back to work until the 22nd, but I did find a solution for my problem and meant to post it. However, when I'm back at work, I'll check yours out and if it is legit I'll give you the answer, along with posting mine. Thank you !

Comment: Hey Matthew, no problem. Do post your answer: multiple solutions are always a good thing. If you still think yours is better by then (i'll keep an eye out >:) ), then nothing wrong with accepting your own!

Comment: Hey @Tom. Could you check my answer and tell me what you think? I originally made it to use ROWID columns. Is there a drawback to my ROWID column method for Classic Rreports that I am not noticing? Is it best to use ROWID columns if your users are paginating on a CR? I'll be posting a more complex answer for IRs that I made which have to take more into account. what is the problem with using a ROWID column on an IR if under Column Definition you uncheck: Allow Users To: Hide, Filter, Control Break, etc. ?

Comment: I've added a classic report the the example page, take a look. And i responded to your comment with a comment on your own post. Spaghetti madness 8)

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback and both of your answers. I am passing the column headers for the next and previous because in my report every column has a link which pulls details into the second report on the page; I should have specified that. The previous and next buttons will activate links in columns that don't exist.

Comment: You have convinced me that the use of a class/CSS to highlight the row rather than `$x_RowHighlight`. I went with ROWID for my reports because the sql is dynamic and the PK can consist of 1,2, or 3 columns on any given run. And I also did not consider how changing a column to type hidden would make it an input with an ID: that is excellent and will be great for future referenec. THANKS! I have to use AJAX instead of f?p due to idiosyncrasies which I should have mentioned in my answer; sorry about that.

Comment: is there a warpper/method like htmldb_get that would do a asynchronous ajax call ?

Comment: Yes, there is a wrapper (see answer edit, i put it there). You can make htmldb_get do an async call since apex 4.0. I'm personally more of a fan on jQuery ajax or post, but that is preference. I'm working on a blogpost on various ajax calls so i can address ajax stuff in the future since this always comes up!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found a solution before Tom posted his. His use of the JQuery index() function is fantastic; I wish I had known about that before hand. On the other hand, like Tom mentioned, the index() would be difficult or impossible to use in the event of pagination. What follows is `The ROWID Column Method`,

I will split this into 2 answers, one for Classic Reports, and one for IR reports.

What follows is for CR.

1)Add a rowid as the first column in the SQL query and set its alias and thus header to " ". In a classic report, set the column width to 1, and under Column Formatting, in CSS Style, put `display:none;`.

2a)Add the following hidden items to your page: `PX_CURRENT_ROW`,`PX_CURRENT_COLUMN`.
2b)If you want a Next and Previous button, and add the following buttons to your page: `NEXT`, `PREVIOUS`.

3)a In the page settings, under JavaScript, and in Execute when Page Loads, add the following:

```
bind_validations(); //Tom will note whom I have learned my APEX/JQ tactics from :)
highlight();
```

3b) In the page settings, under JavaScript, and in Function and Variable Declaration, add the following code for the three functions: identification, highlight, and bind_validations. We will start with the bind validations, which sends the TD of the column when the column link is clicked to the identify_row function. I am using a PLSQL function returning a SQL query for my reports, so all column headers as ID'd by JQuery are generic COL0x. Use an array with your column headers if you are using a regular query.

```
function bind_validations() {
    var columnHeader = 'COL0';
    for (var i = 2; i <10; i++) {
        columnHeader = 'COL0' + i;
        $("td[headers='" + columnHeader + "']").find('a').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                if ($(this).text.length != 0) { //necessary for next/previous buttons 
                    identification(this);
                    window.location.href=this.href; //necessary for next/previous buttons
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

3b) Now comes the identification function. This highlights the row temporarily before the page loads (nice effect for lag, as it lets the user know that row will be activated) using $x_UpTill on the TD passed to the function by the links that were binded in the previous function.

```
function identification(pThis) {
    var currentColumn = $x_UpTill(pThis, 'TD');
    var currentColumnHeader = $(currentColumn).attr('headers');
    var currentRow = $x_UpTill(pThis,'TR');
    var currentRownum = $(currentRow).find("td[headers='COL01']").text(); 
    $x_RowHighlight(currentRow, 'pink');

    //AJAX
    /* As Tom mentions, AJAX is unnecessary: use f?p via column links instead. 
    In my particular situation, the idiosyncrasies render the passing of values
    through f?p inappropriate. The purpose of passing the column header is for
    the previous/next buttons, which will activate blank columns otherwise if 
    everyone of your columns has a link on it.
    */
    var get = new htmldb_Get(null, &APP_ID., 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=dummy', &APP_PAGE_ID.);
    get.add('PX_CURRENT_COLUMN' , currentColumnHeader);
    get.add('PX_CURRENT_ROW', currentRownum);
    gReturn = get.get();
    get = null;
}
```

3)c Here is the highlight function:

```
function highlight() {
    var currentRownum = $v('PX_CURRENT_ROW')
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var rownum = $(this).find("td[headers='COL01']").text(); //Use ' ' if you don't have generic columns like I do
        if (parseInt(rownum) == parseInt(currentRownum)) $x_RowHighlight(this, 'red');
    });
}
```

4) Now add dynamic actions on the next and previous buttons. For the NEXT button, do a dynamic action: Execute JavaScript Code, don't fire on page load:

```
var currentRownum = $v('PX_CURRENT_ROW');
var currentColumnHeader = $v('PX_CURRENT_COLUMN');
$("tr").each(function() {
    var nextRownum = $(this).find("td[headers='COL01']").text();
    if (parseInt(nextRownum) == parseInt(currentRownum) + 1) { //use -1 for the previous button
        $(this).find("td[headers='" + currentColHeader + "']").find('a').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

For the previous button change the condition to: `if (parseInt(nextRownum) == parseInt(currentRownum) - 1)

Comment: Hey Matthew, you found a solution on your own, and that is always great. I didn't provide a solution for a classic report because your question specified an IR, and there are important differences in implementation. Your ROWID usage is ok, and i remarked this as well: you simply require a unique value if you wish the highlight to remain even after pagination. It doesn't have to be ROWID per se, it can be any unique value. Classic reports are great for this though, as you can easily hide the column(s) while still have it render in the HTML, something which an IR does not have.

Comment: As for an IR soution: yes - you could uncheck various options to disallow manipulation on a column, but that could just as well be a drawback and depends on your usercase. I'd not fancy showing a meaningless ID anywhere for example. As for your code, i have some remarks to improve this, but i'll pick these apart in my answer which i will edit so i don't have to flood the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Could you achieve this with using cookies? I've used the [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which I've found very useful.

I don't know anything about oracle-apex, but below is a basic javascript/jquery solution that might work,

```
    $("tr").click(function (){ 
        var activeTR = function (){ 
            $(this).addClass('.active');
            $.cookie("activeTR","activated",({ expires:7, path: '/' }));
        };
    });

    if ($.cookie("activeTR") == "activated"){activeTR()}
```

Basically adding a class to the clicked tr, then adding a cookie to say which is the clicked tr, and then when the page loads it reapplies that class to the clicked tr.

Please note I haven't tried this so It wont work, but it's an idea to get you started.

Comment: Thank you, but apparently some of the end-users do not wish to use cookies :/.

Comment: Ok sorry but I don't have anything else to suggest, with my zero knowledge of `oracle-apex` I don't know what it is capable of. But i will say that cookies are an every day occurrence when browsing the web, so I personally would've said tuff to those end users =P